# Date Format [ 2020, 9, 15 ]: What type of format is this?

Tags: java, json, date, date-format

I'm trying to consume external json, which has a few dates. Format for date is: `[ 2020, 9, 15 ]` I've tried using it as a string but it didn't work.

Can you please tell me what kind of format is this

Comment: Well in terms of JSON, that's an array with three elements. It's an odd way of representing a date, but it's reasonably clear what you should do with it, once you've got it as an array.

Comment: oh yes! it's an array. I completely missed it. Thank you for simplifying and yes, I'm using Jackson library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

Read the JSON number array into a Java `int[]` (`int` array) and construct a `LocalDate` from it.

```
    int[] arrayFromJson = { 2020, 9, 15 };
    System.out.println("Array from JSON: " + Arrays.toString(arrayFromJson));
    
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(arrayFromJson[0], arrayFromJson[1], arrayFromJson[2]);
    System.out.println("Date as LocalDate: " + date);
```

Output is:

> ```
> Array from JSON: [2020, 9, 15]
> Date as LocalDate: 2020-09-15
> ```

`LocalDate` is the class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for representing a date without time of day, so the right class to use here.

### Reading and parsing the JSON

How to read the JSON into Java? It depends on which library you are using for doing that. Here’s an example using Jackson:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = "[ 2020, 9, 15]";

    int[] arrayFromJson = mapper.readValue(json, int[].class);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayFromJson));
```

> ```
> [2020, 9, 15]
> ```

Comment: actually, my json has got a lot of data and date is one of the fields. So I'm using mapper as below:
`Map<String, List<MyObject>> root = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<Map<String, List<MyObject>>>() {});
List<MyObject> objects = root.get("myObject");`
I'm bit confused how would I get the date and map it with pojo.

Comment: How is `MyObject` designed and declared? Has it then got an `int[]` or similar inside of it, or is that nested still deeper?

Comment: can you please refer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64004700/read-array-integer-from-json-and-map-with-pojo